# Sublime Text 2 Command to open User Packages

Tags: sublimetext2

I want to make a simple command that will open all my User packages in sublime. So I created a new plugin and wrote this:

```
import sublime_plugin, os

class UserPackagesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        os.system("subl ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages/User")
```

When I open the console and run view.run_command("user_packages") nothing happens. When I open the command pallet, this command doesn't even show up.

Thanks

Comment: You could just go to `Sublime Text 2 -> Preferences -> Browse Packages...` and go to the `User` folder. Or, you could make your `subl` command an alias in the shell and just run it that way...

Comment: true, I'd like to get this working all in sublime though

Comment: I guess the better question is, what exactly are you trying to accomplish? If you just want to open the directory-picker window when you select `Project -> Add Folder to Project...`, then you can do that with a simple key combination. If it's something bigger, please describe what exactly you're trying to do so we can help.

Comment: I'm still learning about sublime text, and I'd like to create a command that I can call from the command palette.

Comment: If you are learning to write plugins, I'd highly suggest going through http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-a-sublime-text-2-plugin--net-22685. Command palette entries are missing, but there are plenty of examples. Take a look at the `Default.sublime-commands` file in one of your favorite plugins. It basically consist of a name to display, command name, and arguments for the command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
import sublime, sublime_plugin, subprocess

class UserPackagesCommand(sublime_plugin.TextCommand):
    def run(self, edit):
        cmd = []
        cmd.append('subl')
        #cmd.append('-a')
        cmd.append(sublime.installed_packages_path())
        subprocess.Popen(cmd, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=False)
```

To add folders to current project (append to the sidebar) uncomment the `-a` argument line.

**EDIT:**
After editing this now works independently for any OS and ST Package directory path if you have `subl` command available.

Comment: Almost there. view.run_command("user_packages") works but its now showing up in my command pallet...

Comment: You mean it's **NOT** showing up? You need it there?

Comment: It not showing up* I figured it out with the .sublime-commands